# ERROR: gcloud crashed (WindowsError): [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'W:\\'

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am using the Google Cloud SDK shell. When typing the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials test-cluster
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (WindowsError): [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'W:\\'
```

I am unsure why this is happening. This command should just configure `kubectl` to use the cluster I already created called "test-cluster", but it is trying to looking to a drive W:, which I know does not exist.

Comment: which gcloud version are you using? the most current gcloud version is 274.0.1and you can get it [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe) Which version of Windows you have?

Comment: I assume the error arises in the command's attempt to update the local kube config file. This defaults to your home directory's `.kube/config` but can be overridden by `KUBECONFIG` environment variable. Have you possibly set that? And, if so, does it include an errant `W:\\`?

Comment: I am using 274.0.1 and Windows 10 Pro. Also, it looks like I do not have a .kube folder in my home directory. I will investigate this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue:
ERROR: gcloud crashed (WindowsError): [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'Z:\'

No sure why, but what worked for me was running CMD as Administrator

Answer (score 5):

My colleague ran into this issue. he was using windows 10 with docker desktop installed.

DazWilkin has mentioned in the comment on the question about the KUBECONFIG environemnt variable.

that gave us the break to fix the issue, so thank you DazWilkin!

This is how we fixed it:

So he had docker desktop installed but did not enable Kubernetes. So he was missing the {HOME}/.kube/config folder and file. He enabled kubernetes in docker desktop and added the environment variable in the system variables section.

So variable: KUBECONFIG and value: pathtohome.kube\config (C:\users\username.kube\config)

in the system variables section in windows.

That fixed the issue, the command ran fine after that.

Comment: If you need to be OOO in an hour and you have WSL. Then you can try do this from WSL and it should work, but be really slow.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the issue on my end by correctly setting my HOMEDRIVE env variable:

```
set HOMEDRIVE=C:/
```

for some reason, (probably due to bullshit corporate machine setup) it was set to G:/ which pointed nowhere. (use `env` or `echo %HOMEDRIVE%` to view the current value)